# Windows cant open .zip file in CMD

Tags: cmd, zip

Im trying to install Elasticsearch and Kibana in my anserini folder, but the command they give to install it doesnt work. The "Elastarini" folder is made, but CMD tells me "Failed to open elasticsearch.zip". I also tried different fileendings such as .rar and.gz.

The file itself is called "elasticsearch-7.0.0-windows-x86_64.zip".
Does anyone have an Idea on how to get windows to correctly extract this file into the new folder?
Thanks

```
mkdir elastirini && tar -zxvf elasticsearch*.zip-C elastirini --strip-components=
```

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't some missing whitespace here `elasticsearch*.zip-C`? `…tar.exe -xf elasticsearch-*.zip -C …`

Comment: What `tar.exe` command are you using? is it the one delivered with recent Windows 10 versions, or is it some third-party tool? Anyway, you should read its documentation…

Comment: The solution was to rename "elasticserach*.zip" to  "elasticearch.zip" and rename the zip file to also only be named "elasticsearch". then it found the file

Comment: If your version of `tar.exe` does not accept the wildcard, which I assume by your above comment, is the case, your command would look more like this: `md elastirini 2>nul & for %a in ("elasticsearch-*.zip") do tar.exe -xf "%a" -C elastirini …`. Either way, I can categorically tell you that the rename doesn't solve it, because `elasticsearch.zip-C` would still be wrong, and you'd have received an error message telling you `Error opening archive: Failed to open 'elasticsearch.zip-C'`. With the rename, it would look more like: `md elastirini 2>nul & tar.exe -xf elasticsearch.zip -C elastirini …`.